# printf() function executes after time() function? C/C++

Tags: c++

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
int main()

{
time_t t;
int d;
printf("\nHello 1");    
    time(&t);           
    d=t;
    while (t-d<3) /*wait 3 seconds*/
    {
        time(&t);
    }
printf("\nHello 2");
    time(&t);
    d=t;
    while (t-d<3)  /*wait 3 seconds*/
    {
        time(&t);
    }
printf("\nHello 3");
return 0;
}
```

after build the program, i run it. The program waits 3 seconds to show the line "Hello 1".

why is it written first but executed later?

Comment: It looks like the execution is in-order but th output is buffered. Try adding `fflush(stdout);` just after each `printf` calls.

Comment: Put the `\n` after strings and not before, to force the line-buffered output.

Comment: Move the '\n' to the end of the string. New line will flush the buffer

Comment: thanks you very much!

Comment: In general, put `'\n'` at the end of the line. Don't reflexively flush the output. Writing a newline will almost always be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

On some OS, the output buffer `stdout` typically needs to be "flushed" in order to make what you print there appear on screen. The `\n` acts as a "flush" and that explains the behavior.

You can fix this by adding a `fflush(stdout);` call after each `printf`. This forces a screen update. Alternatively move the `\n` to the end of each line instead of at the beginning.

Comment: Asked many times before

Comment: @0___________ Probably, but I'm not aware of a canonical dupe, especially not in C++.

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to flush the buffer. So the simplest thing is to move from this: `printf("\nHello 1");` to  `printf("Hello 1\n");`

Try this https://onlinegdb.com/u5L2xtwgf